# Dart converting int? timestamp to date gives me wrong date

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a timestamp like so:

```
int? completedTimestamp; //1657948481451
```

When I try to convert this to a date like so:

```
var date = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(completedTimestamp!, isUtc: true);
```

date returns this:

```
1970-01-20 04:32:28
```

I am expecting 2022-07-16 5:14:41

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert timestamp with milliseconds to date as below:

```
 var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(completedTimestamp!, isUtc: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp you're using is a count of milliseconds since the epoch, so you want to use `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()`, not `fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch()`.

`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()` will return the correct timestamp of `2022-07-16 05:14:41.451Z`.